# How to COUNT values according to mult criteria and using OR logic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count values according to multiple criteria based on two separate columns. This is the function I have written.

```
=COUNTIFS([Category2],"Account Management",[VA/NVA/NNVA/D],{"NVA","NNVA"})
```

Essentially, the function is supposed to look in Column D to see if it says "Account Management", THEN it looks two columns over at Column F to see if it says "NVA" OR "NNVA". If it says either, it gets a count.

However, my function is returning a value of 5 when it should be 39.

[Here is a picture of the spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWo6N.png)

Comment: wrap in SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding sum should do the trick:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS([Category 2],"Account Management",[VA/NVA/NNVA/D],{"NVA","NNVA"}))
```

I found this trick at [Excel Jet](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) and tried the formula without actually reading the explanation so I cannot relay the logic behind this.

Comment: No problem here, if the criteria are "hard coded" as they are here `SUM` works.  If the criteria is a range of cells in which the criteria is found then `SUMPRODUCT` is needed.  `SUMPRODUCT` also works with "hard coded"

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey Scott, can you give an example of how this function would look using SUMPRODUCT? I'm weak in this area.

Comment: @stephenp just like above but instead of `SUM` you would put `SUMPRODUCT`